# Paying for gas (when the SC is executed) with money stored in a SC

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, payments

I am starting to program my first real contract and would like to ask if it is possible to do this (something like an auction):

Someone deploys a contract. Participants pay for that auction to run (money that is stored in the contract). Then, after X time, the contract is executed. This execution is paid for with the money that was stored in the contract. Therefore, if there is not enough money, the execution will fail (and the participants will have to put more money next time).

P.S: I am also trying to prevent a participant from registering twice in the auction (or not registering if he doesn't have enough Ether). Should I store their addresses and check them every time a new participant registers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may anyone help me, please?

Comment: May anyone help me?